# How to create a multi-step form with smooth transitions between steps?

Tags: jquery, forms, css

Using jQuery (and if needed CSS3), how can one create a multi-step form with smooth transitions between steps?

For example, if I have a three step form like this, how can I make smooth the transitions between steps?

```js
//shows #form_part{n} and hides the other parts
function shows_form_part(n){

  var i = 1, p = $("#form_part"+(i).toString());
  while (p.length != 0){

      if (i == n){
          p.show();
      }
      else{
          p.hide();        
      }
      i++;
      p = $("#form_part"+(i).toString());
  }

}

//change accordingly, just an example
function submit_form() {
  var sum = Number($("#num1").val()) + 
            Number($("#num2").val()) + 
            Number($("#num3").val());
  alert("The sum result is: " + sum);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onload="shows_form_part(1)">
<form>
  <div id="form_part1">
    Part 1<br>
    <input type="number" value="1" id="num1"><br>
    <!--form elements 1-->
    <button type="button" onclick="shows_form_part(2)">&raquo;</button>
  </div>
  <div id="form_part2">
    Part 2<br>
    <input type="number" value="2" id="num2"><br>
    <!--form elements 2-->
    <button type="button" onclick="shows_form_part(1)">&laquo;</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="shows_form_part(3)">&raquo;</button>
  </div>
  <div id="form_part3">
    Part 3<br>
    <!--form elements 3-->
    <input type="number" value="3" id="num3"><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="shows_form_part(2)">&laquo;</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="submit_form()">Sum</button>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: @LGSon, I made the question and I gave the reply right from the beginning, in order to help community. In any case, I edited the question as you referred.

Comment: Retraced my downvotes :) ...and as you probably understood, it does not matter if you intend to answer your own question, it needs to be proper written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way to achieve that is using parameters in jQuery method `.show(speed)` and `.hide(speed)` for each form step `div`. The speed parameter may be `"slow"`, `"fast"` or the time in milliseconds for the transition.

Then one needs a function that shows and hides the corresponding form step `div`s. The following function shows only `#form_part{n}` and hides the other form parts. In the `HTML` part, one just needs to have each form step `div` orderly named with the `id="form_part{n}"`, i.e., `form_part1`, `form_part2`, etc.

```js
//shows #form_part{n} and hides the other parts
function shows_form_part(n){

  var i = 1, p = $("#form_part"+(i).toString());
  while (p.length != 0){

      if (i == n){
          p.show("slow");
      }
      else{
          p.hide("slow");        
      }
      i++;
      p = $("#form_part"+(i).toString());
  }

}

//change accordingly, just an example
function submit_form() {
  var sum = Number($("#num1").val()) + 
            Number($("#num2").val()) + 
            Number($("#num3").val());
  alert("The sum result is: " + sum);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onload="shows_form_part(1)">
<form>
  <div id="form_part1">
    Part 1<br>
    <input type="number" value="1" id="num1"><br>
    <!--form elements 1-->
    <button type="button" onclick="shows_form_part(2)">&raquo;</button>
  </div>
  <div id="form_part2">
    Part 2<br>
    <input type="number" value="2" id="num2"><br>
    <!--form elements 2-->
    <button type="button" onclick="shows_form_part(1)">&laquo;</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="shows_form_part(3)">&raquo;</button>
  </div>
  <div id="form_part3">
    Part 3<br>
    <!--form elements 3-->
    <input type="number" value="3" id="num3"><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="shows_form_part(2)">&laquo;</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="submit_form()">Sum</button>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
```

Test here. It works :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var navListItems = $('div.setup-panel div a'),
          allWells = $('.setup-content'),
          allNextBtn = $('.nextBtn');

  allWells.hide();

  navListItems.click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
              $item = $(this);

      if (!$item.hasClass('disabled')) {
          navListItems.removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default');
          $item.addClass('btn-primary');
          allWells.hide();
          $target.show();
          $target.find('input:eq(0)').focus();
      }
  });

  allNextBtn.click(function(){
      var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
          curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
          nextStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().next().children("a"),
          curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url']"),
          isValid = true;

      $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
      for(var i=0; i<curInputs.length; i++){
          if (!curInputs[i].validity.valid){
              isValid = false;
              $(curInputs[i]).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
          }
      }

      if (isValid)
          nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
  });

  $('div.setup-panel div a.btn-primary').trigger('click');
});
```

```css
body {
    margin-top:40px;
}
.stepwizard-step p {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.stepwizard-row {
    display: table-row;
}
.stepwizard {
    display: table;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
}
.stepwizard-step button[disabled] {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100) !important;
}
.stepwizard-row:before {
    top: 14px;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    content: " ";
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    z-order: 0;
}
.stepwizard-step {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
.btn-circle {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 6px 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  
<div class="stepwizard col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="stepwizard-row setup-panel">
      <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a href="#step-1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">1</a>
        <p>Step 1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a href="#step-2" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">2</a>
        <p>Step 2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a href="#step-3" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">3</a>
        <p>Step 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <form role="form" action="" method="post">
    <div class="row setup-content" id="step-1">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h3> Step 1</h3>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
            <input  maxlength="100" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name"  />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
            <input maxlength="100" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Last Name" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Address</label>
            <textarea required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your address" ></textarea>
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button" >Next</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row setup-content" id="step-2">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h3> Step 2</h3>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Company Name</label>
            <input maxlength="200" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Name" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Company Address</label>
            <input maxlength="200" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Address"  />
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button" >Next</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row setup-content" id="step-3">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h3> Step 3</h3>
          <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  
</div>
```

Example From: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/e3MBM

Comment: Thanks, but there is no smooth transition between steps.

Comment: idk why it isn't working here, but look here: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/e3MBM

Comment: I saw the link, and there is no smooth transitions